# Using a while loop in Java to count sentences

Tags: java, file, loops, while-loop

***UPDATE:

Figured it out with the help of everyone and some friends! I needed to catch the \n character in the string variable as well as the empty string. Thank you to everyone who commented and helped!***

This is for an assignment for Intro to Java, we haven't gotten to methods yet and when googling for help that was the only thing popping up so I figured I might as well attempt asking myself.

Thanks in advance!

For our project we have to create a program that calculates the FRI of some simple texts and I'm having two problems.

This first problem is that while counting sentences from a file using a Scanner object and a while loop my count is always wrong by +1. I can see in the console print out that it's counting the empty string, the \n that prints out (I'm printing to the console so I can see what the variable is being given, not because it's required) even though I have it set to only increase my accumulating variable if my string isn't empty.

Any help would be appreciated!
I'm not sure what parts of my code are needed, but...

```
/* Count Sentences */
//Scanner object to read inputText
Scanner countSentences = new Scanner(inputText);

// While loop to count sentences
while(countSentences.hasNext()){
    String sentence = countSentences.useDelimiter(SENTENCE_DELIMITERS).next();
    System.out.println(sentence);
    if(sentence.compareTo("") != 0){
        numSentences++;
    }
}
```

...is the bit where the sentence counting takes place.

Thanks again!

Entire code! Edit:

DESCRIPTION:
A program to calculate the Flesch Readability Index of a text

```
public class Readability {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        final double FIRST_CONSTANT = -1.015;               //First constant of FRI formula
        final double SECOND_CONSTANT = 84.6;                //Second constant of FRI formula
        final double THIRD_COSTANT = 206.835;               //Third constant of FRI formula
        final String SENTENCE_DELIMITERS = "[.:;?!]";       //Sentence delimiters
        final String WORD_DELIMITERS = "[.:;?! ,\t,\n]";    //Word delimiters
        
        int numSentences = 0;                               //Number of sentences in inputText
        int numWords = 0;                                   //Number of words in inputText
        int numSyllables = 0;                               //Number of syllables in each word in inputText
        
        String standardText = "This is just a test.";       //Standard Text for testing
        String inputText = "";                              //Holds the text being tested currently
        
        /* Ask user if they want to run a text analysis */
        int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to run a text analysis?", "Start the Flesch Reading Ease Test", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        
        /* Message Displayed if 'No' selected, and program exits */
        if(choice == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The program exits. Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
        /* If user selects 'Yes' */
        // Ask user if they have a text file or wish to use the standard text
        choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Answer \"Yes\" if you want to read the text from a file!\nAnswer \"No\" if you want a test run on a standard text.", "Select the input!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        
            /* If user selects 'Yes' */
            if(choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                // Ask user for filename
                String inputFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter input file name with extension!\nInclude the path if file is not in the project folder!");
                
                    // User presses cancel, set inputText to standardText 
                    if(inputFileName == null){
                        inputText = standardText;
                    }
                    
                    // User presses enter, create file object using user input as filename
                    else{
                        File file = new File(inputFileName);
                    
                    // Check if file exists, if file exists create scanner object to read text from file
                    if(file.exists()){
                        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(file);
                        
                        // Read the file line by line and collect the concatenated lines in the variable inputText
                        while(readFile.hasNext()){
                            String fileSentences = readFile.nextLine();
                            inputText += fileSentences + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                    // If file doesn't exist, set inputText to the standardText
                    else {
                        inputText = standardText;
                    }
                    }
            }
        
            /* If user selects 'No' */
            else{
                inputText = standardText;
            }    
        
            /* Count Sentences */
            //Scanner object to read inputText
            Scanner countSentences = new Scanner(inputText);
            
            // While loop to count sentences
            while(countSentences.hasNext()){
                String sentence = countSentences.useDelimiter(SENTENCE_DELIMITERS).next();
                System.out.println(sentence);
                if(sentence.length() != 0){
                    numSentences++;
                }
                System.out.println(numSentences); //This println prints the correct number to the console
            }
            System.out.println(numSentences);  //This println prints +1
            
            //Close countSentences scanner
            countSentences.close();
            
            /* Count Words */
            //Scanner object to read inputText
            Scanner countWords = new Scanner(inputText);
            
            // While loop to count words and increment syllable count per word (rule #3: each word has at least one syllable)
            while(countWords.hasNext()){
                String word = countWords.useDelimiter(WORD_DELIMITERS).next();
                
                if(word.compareTo("") != 0){
                    numWords++;
                    //numSyllables++;
                }
                
                // For loop to count syllables as each word is read
                for(int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++){
                    char letter = word.charAt(k);
                    
                    
                }
            }
            
    //Test//
    System.out.println(inputText);
    System.out.println(numSentences);
    System.out.println(numWords);
    System.out.println(numSyllables);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: A guess: try replacing `sentence.compareTo("")` with `sentence.trim().compareTo("")`

Comment: Can't :( It isn't a command we've learned. I can only use what we've learned in class up to this point and what the book has given us.

Comment: What is `SENTENCE_DELIMITERS`?

Comment: final String SENTENCE_DELIMITERS = "[.:;?!]";       //Sentence delimiters

Comment: Whats your input string? This program worked fine for me.

Comment: What!? That is awful!  <---- The String our professor has to test.

Should count out 2 sentences, is printing 3 in mine.

Comment: When printing numSentences in the loop it comes out correct for me. The problem is elsewhere in my code *headdesk*

Comment: I don't see any issues with this code. Could you share the complete code?

Comment: Figured out how to share code: Updated post.

It prints correctly in the while loop, but +1 immediately outside.

Comment: @Cheyko, That means there is an issue outside this code. Please check the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working program. It gave me result as 2.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Scannerd {

      public static String inputText = "What!? That is awful!";

      public static String SENTENCE_DELIMITERS = "[.:;?!]";

            public static void main(String... arg) {
              int numSentences = 0;

              Scanner countSentences = new Scanner(inputText);

              // While loop to count sentences
              while (countSentences.hasNext()) {
                String sentence = countSentences.useDelimiter(SENTENCE_DELIMITERS).next();
                System.out.println(sentence);
                if(sentence.compareTo("") != 0){
                  numSentences++;
                }

              }
              System.out.println("#ofSentences"+numSentences);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it uses the default delimiter in the beginning since the custom delimiter is used inside the loop.
Try this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestScanner {

  public static String inputText = "What!? That is awful!";

  public static String SENTENCE_DELIMITERS = "[.:;?!]";

        public static void main(String... arg) {
          int numSentences = 0;

          Scanner countSentences = new Scanner(inputText);
          countSentences.useDelimiter(SENTENCE_DELIMITERS);
          // While loop to count sentences
          while (countSentences.hasNext()) {
            //String sentence = countSentences.useDelimiter(SENTENCE_DELIMITERS).next();
              String sentence = countSentences.next();
            System.out.println(sentence);
            if(sentence.compareTo("") != 0){
              numSentences++;
            }

          }
          System.out.println("#ofSentences"+numSentences);
        }
}
```

Comment: Nope :(, still didn't work for me. Continues to print the correct value inside the loop, and then the wrong value +1 outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hasNextLine() and nextLine() methods.

```
/* Count Sentences */
//Scanner object to read inputText
Scanner countSentences = new Scanner(inputText);

// While loop to count sentences
while(countSentences.hasNextLine()){
    String sentence = countSentences.useDelimiter(SENTENCE_DELIMITERS).nextLine();
    System.out.println(sentence);
    if(sentence.compareTo("") != 0){
        numSentences++;
    }
}
```